# Report builder says Cucumber is not a valid report

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I have used below code for creating html reports , this code is present in after class of Junit Runner in a cucumber framework , but am getting error saying cucumber.json is not a valid cucumber report. I am assuming that report builder is trying to get the cucumber.json even before it is created completely,
    I kept code in cucumber options to create Json file

```
@CucumberOptions(features = "features/", 
glue = { "report"}, 
format = {"pretty","json:target/cucumber.json"},
tags = {"@testing" }, monochrome = true)

    private void generateReportForJsonFiles(File reportOutputDirectory,
            List<String> jsonFiles) {
        String jenkinsBasePath = "";
        String buildNumber = "1";
        String projectName = project.getName();

        Configuration configuration = new Configuration(reportOutputDirectory, projectName);
        configuration.setParallelTesting(false);
        configuration.setJenkinsBasePath(jenkinsBasePath);
        configuration.setRunWithJenkins(false);
        configuration.setBuildNumber(buildNumber);

        ReportBuilder reportBuilder = new ReportBuilder(jsonFiles, configuration);
        reportBuilder.generateReports();


        }

Below is the error:

File 'target/cucumber.json' is not proper Cucumber report!
```

Comment: Could you please provide a bit more information. **1)** What cause is shown by the `net.masterthought.cucumber.ValidationException`. **2)** Which versions you are using for `net.masterthought:cucumber-reporting` and `io.cucumber:*`.

Comment: Have you checked that `target/cucumber.json` is not empty or at least looks like a valid Cucumber report?

Comment: @SubOptimal : Yes , i tested it by placing Cucumber.json at some other path manually and gave the json path for report builder , it worked ! , so i am guessing , report builder is trying to find the cucumber json file even before it getting created.

Comment: INFO: Unexpected error
net.masterthought.cucumber.ValidationException: File 'target/cucumber.json' is not proper Cucumber report! this is the error , cucumber report version is <version>4.2.0</version> and cucumber version is 1.2.5

Comment: Please provide a working example to reproduce your issue. See my answer for a working example.

Answer (score 3):

- you should provide a small example ([MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) which others can use to reproduce your problem
- your code snippet `configuration.setParallelTesting(false)` and your answer `cucumber report version is <version>4.2.0</version>` do not match, as the method `configuration.setParallelTesting` was removed in version `4.1.0`

Have a look at this small working snippet (based on the few information you provided).

Assume the following structure

```
pom.xml
src/main/java/CreateReport.java
src/main/resources/log4j2.properties
src/test/java/TestRunner.java
src/test/java/stepdefs/StepDefinitions.java
src/test/resource/features/demo.feature
```

**pom.xml**

```
...
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <!--
        info.cukes:cucumber-java:1.2.5 is quite old and has been superseded by
        io.cucumber:cucumber-java  see: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java
    -->
    <version.cucumber>1.2.5</version.cucumber>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>${version.cucumber}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>${version.cucumber}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
...
```

**CreateReport.java**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import net.masterthought.cucumber.Configuration;
import net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportBuilder;

public class CreateReport {

    private void generateReportForJsonFiles(File reportOutputDirectory, List<String> jsonFiles) {
        String buildNumber = "1";
        String projectName = "StackOverflow example";

        Configuration configuration = new Configuration(reportOutputDirectory, projectName);
        configuration.setParallelTesting(false);
//        configuration.setJenkinsBasePath(jenkinsBasePath);
        configuration.setRunWithJenkins(false);
        configuration.setBuildNumber(buildNumber);

        ReportBuilder reportBuilder = new ReportBuilder(jsonFiles, configuration);
        reportBuilder.generateReports();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new CreateReport().generateReportForJsonFiles(new File("target/"),
                Arrays.asList("target/cucumber.json"));
    }
}
```

**log4j2.properties**

```
status = info
name = PropertiesConfig
appenders = console
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = [%level] %m%n
rootLogger.level = info
rootLogger.appenderRefs = stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
```

**TestRunner.java**

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = {"src/test/resource/features"},
        glue = {"stepdefs"},
        plugin = {"json:target/cucumber.json"}
         )
public class TestRunner {
}
```

**StepDefinitions.java**

```
package stepdefs;

import org.junit.Assert;

import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;

public class StepDefinitions {
    @Given("^a successful step$")
    public void aSuccessfulStep() throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("a successful step");
    }

    @Given("^a not successful step$")
    public void aNotSuccessfulStep() throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("a not successful step");
        Assert.fail();
    }
}
```

**demo.feature**

Feature: Test cucumber reporting plugin

```
Scenario: Run a non failing scenario
  Given a successful step

Scenario: Run a failing scenario
  Given a not successful step
```

- run the Cucumber test (this creates the `target/cucumber.json` file)

  ```
  $ mvn clean test
  ```
- run the report creator (

  ```
  $ mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=CreateReport
  ...
  12:55:21 [INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (default-cli) @ cuke-test23.so ---
  Dec 18, 2018 12:55:22 PM net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportParser parseJsonFiles
  INFO: File 'target/cucumber.json' contains 1 features
  ```
- the report is generated in `target/cucumber-html-reports/overview-features.html`